# jquery issue in php loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops, parent

Need help here.

I am creating share button like youtube (if clicked it will give you div popup and share links) i got working script it worked for single button but when i put this inside loop it is not working properly when i click 4th button it will open div at first button acctually it has to open 4th div in short if i click 2nd button it should open 2nd div if i click 3rd button 3rd div should open  same for all

Here is my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.share_button').mouseenter(function(e) {
   $('.tooltip').show();
            $('.share_this').fadeIn(200);
        }).mouseleave(function(e) {
   $('.share_this').fadeOut(200);
   $('.tooltip').hide();
        });
  
  $('.share_button').click(function(){
   $('#load_buttons_box').fadeIn();
    
  }); 
    });
 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 
 $('#shortLink').click(function(){
 
  if($('#shortLink').is(':checked'))
  {
   $('#setURL').val($("#shareLink").val()); // to save previous link
   var a = $("#shareLink").val();
  
   $.post("getShortLink.php?value="+a, {
   }, function(response){
    $('#shareLink').val(response);
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#shareLink').val($('#setURL').val());
  }
 }); 
 
 $('.close').click(function(){
  $('#load_buttons_box').fadeOut();
 }); 
}); 
 
</script>
```

```css
button {
 -moz-background-clip:border;
 -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
 -moz-background-origin:padding;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
 background:#F6F6F6 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding:5px;
 height:2.0833em;
 overflow:visible;
 vertical-align:middle;
 white-space:nowrap;
}

.share_button{background:url(share.png) center left no-repeat; padding-left:50px; }

.facebook_button{background:url(facebook.png) center left no-repeat; padding-left:20px; float:left }

.tooltip{ height:13px;display: none;width:120px; text-align:left;overflow:visible}

.share_this{
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  height:17px;
  padding:7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width:60px;
  background-color:#333333;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: #fff 0px 0px 20px;
 }

#load_buttons_box{ 
  border:solid #666666 1px; height:140px; 
  margin-top:19px;-moz-border-radius: 6px;
  display:none;
  padding-left:30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px; width:500px;
  }
  
.twitter_button{background:url(twitter.png) center left no-repeat; padding-left:20px; float:left; margin-left:4px;  }

.buzz_button{background:url(buzz.png) center left no-repeat; padding-left:25px; float:left; margin-left:4px;  }

.bebo_button{background:url(bebo.gif) center left no-repeat; padding-left:21px; float:left; margin-left:4px;  }

.stumbleupon_button{background:url(stumbleupon.gif) center left no-repeat; padding-left:20px; float:left; margin-left:4px;  }

.share_button:hover, .facebook_button:hover, .twitter_button:hover, .buzz_button:hover, .bebo_button:hover, .stumbleupon_button:hover{
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
  
.mesgbox{
 padding-left:25px;  
 margin:5px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size:12px; height:20px;  
 width:427px; float:left}

.close{ 
 border:solid #666666 1px; 
 float:left; 
 width:20px; margin-top:6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;  text-align:center; 
 font-size:12px; cursor:pointer; 
 background-color:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.textBox{ 
 background:url(ico.png) center left no-repeat;
 height:22px;
 width:300px;
 padding-left:25px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
}
#shortLink{ 
 margin-top:10px;
 }
.textBox label{ cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
<h1>Youtube Style Share Button With URL Shortening using CURL, jQuery and PHP.</h1>
<br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />

<?php
for($a=0;$a<=5;$a++) { ?>

<div align="left" style="margin-left:50px;">

 <div align="left" style="height:0px;">
  <div class="tooltip">
   <span class="share_this">
   Share this video
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
 
 <button type="button" class="share_button" onclick=";return false;" id="like" >
 <span>Share</span></button>

 <br clear="all" />
 
 <div id="load_buttons_box">
 
  <div class="mesgbox">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="close">X</div>
  <br clear="all" />
  
  <div class="textBox">
   <input type="text" name="shareLink" id="shareLink" value="http://www.99points.info/2010/07/youtube-style-share-button-with-url-shortening-using-curl-jquery-and-php" size="60" />
   <input type="hidden" name="setURL" id="setURL" value="" /> 
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="shortLink" id="shortLink" />Short URL</label>
  </div>
  <br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />
  
  <button type="button" class="facebook_button" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.99points.info/2010/07/youtube-style-share-button-with-url-shortening-using-curl-jquery-and-php&t=Youtube Style Share Button With URL Shortening using CURL, jQuery and PHP','mywindow','width=800,height=500,left=0,top=0,screenX=0,screenY=100')" >
  <span>Facebook</span></button>
  
  <button type="button" class="twitter_button" onClick="window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status=Youtube Style Share Button using jQuery http%3A//www.99points.info/2010/07/youtube-style-share-button-with-url-shortening-using-curl-jquery-and-php','mywindow','width=800,height=500,left=0,top=0,screenX=0,screenY=100')" >
  <span>Twitter</span></button>
  
  <button type="button" class="buzz_button" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com/buzz/post?url=http%3A//www.99points.info/2010/07/youtube-style-share-button-with-url-shortening-using-curl-jquery-and-php','mywindow','width=800,height=500,left=0,top=0,screenX=0,screenY=100')" >
  <span>Buzz</span></button>
  
  <button type="button" class="bebo_button" onClick="window.open('http://www.bebo.com/c/share?Url=http%3A//www.99points.info/2010/07/youtube-style-share-button-with-url-shortening-using-curl-jquery-and-php&Title=Youtube Style Share Button With URL Shortening using CURL, jQuery and PHP&TUUID=c583051f-6b2d-41ec-8dd0-a3a0ee1656c1&MID=8348657161','mywindow','width=800,height=500,left=0,top=0,screenX=0,screenY=100')" >
  <span>Bebo</span></button>
  
  <button type="button" class="stumbleupon_button" onClick="window.open('http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http%3A//www.99points.info/2010/07/youtube-style-share-button-with-url-shortening-using-curl-jquery-and-php&title=Youtube%20Style%20Share%20Button With%20URL%20Shortening%20using%20CURL%20jQuery%20and%20PHP','mywindow','width=800,height=500,left=0,top=0,screenX=0,screenY=100')" >
  <span>StumbleUpon</span></button>
  
  <br clear="all" />
 </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: From a quick glance it seems that your ID's are identical, ID's needs to be unique.

Comment: Use `find` method to find elements that you need. And also - `id` should be unique.

Comment: Yes this is Resolved but by repeating functions and adding separate ids if any body let me know best practice for this.   Can we do this in one jquery function.

Comment: Instead of repeating the jQuery functions you should try to find out how you can make one function, `this` usually helps you to make one function that operates with different ID's.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do. Let me know if I missed out anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.share_button').mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(this).siblings().children('.tooltip').show();
        $('.share_this').fadeIn(200);
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $('.share_this').fadeOut(200);
        $(this).siblings().children('.tooltip').hide();
    });

    $('.share_button').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('#load_buttons_box').fadeIn();

    }); 

    $('#shortLink').click(function(){

        if($('#shortLink').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('#setURL').val($("#shareLink").val()); // to save previous link
            var a = $("#shareLink").val();

            $.post("getShortLink.php?value="+a, {
            }, function(response){
                $('#shareLink').val(response);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#shareLink').val($('#setURL').val());
        }
    }); 

    $('.close').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    }); 
});
```